# Is this defined?

Tags: c++, constants, language-lawyer

Suppose I have the following class:

```
struct A{
  void method(A& otherA) const{
    /* Mutate otherA */
  }
};
```

And then later I have this:

```
A myA;
myA.method(myA);
```

I have told the compiler that `method` will not change the `this` instance, but does the compiler realize that I could pass in the `this` instance as a parameter?

Could I be breaking stuff by doing this?  Is this defined behavior?

Comment: Yes you can do it. Compiler couldn't know whether they're the same instance. You should make the parameter type `const` if you don't want the passed parameter being changed.

Comment: @songyuanyao No....but I do want to change it

Comment: Then it'll be fine. You can change it via passed argument.

Comment: `const` means the object will not be changed via `this->` in the method, but it may still be changed by other means

Comment: On a side note: Compilers usually don't optize based on the constness of function arguments (including the this pointer) at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is totally fine, and not a problem. What you're doing in this example is sometimes called "aliasing" - when two arguments actually refer to the same object.

Consider the even simpler case in plain C:

```
void foo(int* a, const int* b) { *a += *b; }
```

That function takes two pointers to `int`s, and adds the second one to the first one. And of course this code to use my `foo` function is perfectly valid:

```
int x = 10;
foo(&x, &x); // now x is 20
```

If you don't like that behavior in this case, the best thing to do would be probably to add a check within your method like

```
void A::method(A& otherA) const {
    if (this == &otherA) { /* aliasing detected */ }
    else { /* proceed as normal */ }
}
```

Comment: My main concern was that my program might be relying on "undefined behavior" so I just wanted to double check.....thanks